# Are XFS volumes conceptually same as linux logical volumes?

Tags: lvm, xfs, terminology

According to the [Wikipedia page for XFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS), the XFS file system supports:

Max. volume size: 8 exbibytes − 1 byte

Max. file size: 8 exbibytes − 1 byte

(Refer to the info-box on right side of the page)

What does "Maximum Volume Size" mean in this page?

I am familiar with Linux LVMs. I know that a logical volume can be formatted with the XFS file system. But I have never seen logical volumes as a feature of a particular file system.

Comment: No…Wikipedia like to use that word on Filesystem Type Pages to mention the size of a filesystem. The phrase you mentioned in your question means the maximum possible size of a XFS is 8EiB-1B

Answer (score 0):

> Are XFS volumes conceptually same as linux logical volumes?

No.  [XFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) is a type of filesystem. [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) is a framework that allows a very flexible volume management.

> What does "Maximum Volume Size" mean in this page?

The maximum possible size of a partition formatted in XFS (that is, containing a XFS filesystem).